# How to make curved navigation bar in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I want to create to navigation-bar in React-Native like this I have searched more but couldn't get success.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qwppj.png)

Comment: There are many ways to achieve it. try it yourself. if you still not making it post what you tried. I recommend using a snack. after that you'll have much better chances to get help from the community.

Comment: I have used almost libraries but not get required output.

Answer (score 0):

here is an example using Svg, i just created ui for the curves i hope you implement this in tab bar, in the your tabs. you can check snack link

snack: https://snack.expo.dev/@ashwith00/react-navigation-5-boilerplate

code:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {
  Animated,
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  useWindowDimensions,
} from 'react-native';
import Svg, { Path, Line } from 'react-native-svg';
import Constants from 'expo-constants';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function TestScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.content}>
      <Button mode="contained" style={styles.button}>
        Push new screen
      </Button>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function MyStack() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator tabBar={(props) => <MyTabBar {...props} />}>
      <Tab.Screen name="Test1" component={TestScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Test2" component={TestScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Test3" component={TestScreen} />
      <Tab.Screen name="Test4" component={TestScreen} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MyStack />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

const tabBarHeight = 80;
const middleIconSize = 50;
const midRadius = 25;
const midBoundary = 60;
function MyTabBar({ state, descriptors, navigation }) {
  const { width } = useWindowDimensions();

  const path = [
    'M0 0',
    `H${width / 2 - midBoundary / 2}`,
    `A 10 10 0 0 0 ${width / 2 + midBoundary / 2} 0`,
    `H${width}`,
    `V${tabBarHeight}`,
    'H0',
    `z`,
  ].join(',');

  const linePath = [
    'M0 0',
    `H${width / 2 - midBoundary / 2}`,
    `A 10 10 0 0 0 ${width / 2 + midBoundary / 2} 0`,
    `H${width}`,
  ].join(',');
  return (
    <View
      style={{ alignSelf: 'stretch', height: tabBarHeight, paddingBottom: 20 }}>
      <Svg
        viewBox={`0 0 ${width} ${tabBarHeight}`}
        height={tabBarHeight}
        width={width}>
        <Path d={path} fill="yellow" />
        <Path d={linePath} fill="transparent" strokeWidth={1} stroke="#ccc" />
      </Svg>
      <View
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
          width: middleIconSize,
          height: middleIconSize,
          borderRadius: midRadius,
          backgroundColor: 'red',
          left: width / 2 - midRadius,
          bottom: tabBarHeight - midRadius,
        }}
      />
      <View style={{ ...StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject, flexDirection: 'row', bottom: 20 }}>
        {state.routes.map((route, index) => {
          const { options } = descriptors[route.key];
          const label =
            options.tabBarLabel !== undefined
              ? options.tabBarLabel
              : options.title !== undefined
              ? options.title
              : route.name;

          const isFocused = state.index === index;

          const onPress = () => {
            const event = navigation.emit({
              type: 'tabPress',
              target: route.key,
              canPreventDefault: true,
            });

            if (!isFocused && !event.defaultPrevented) {
              // The `merge: true` option makes sure that the params inside the tab screen are preserved
              navigation.navigate({ name: route.name, merge: true });
            }
          };

          const onLongPress = () => {
            navigation.emit({
              type: 'tabLongPress',
              target: route.key,
            });
          };

          return (
            <TouchableOpacity
              accessibilityRole="button"
              accessibilityState={isFocused ? { selected: true } : {}}
              accessibilityLabel={options.tabBarAccessibilityLabel}
              testID={options.tabBarTestID}
              onPress={onPress}
              onLongPress={onLongPress}
              style={[
                { flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center',alignItems:'center' },
                index === 1 && { marginRight: midBoundary / 2  },
                index === 2 && { marginLeft: midBoundary / 2 },
              ]}>
              <Text style={{ color: isFocused ? '#673ab7' : '#222' }}>
                {label}
              </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
          );
        })}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    margin: 8,
  },
  content: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 8,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

[image]

Comment: perfect!! Now, how to insert bottomTab in above code?