# How can I make this curved svg pressable?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-svg

I want to have a curved svg and want to ask you how to can I make this red circle pressable ?

[Curved Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68814949/how-to-make-curved-navigation-bar-in-react-native)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Pressable` instead of `View` Component.

```
<View
  style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    width: middleIconSize,
    height: middleIconSize,
    borderRadius: midRadius,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    left: width / 2 - midRadius,
    bottom: tabBarHeight - midRadius,
  }}
/>
```

to

```
<Pressable
  style={{
    position: 'absolute',
    width: middleIconSize,
    height: middleIconSize,
    borderRadius: midRadius,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    left: width / 2 - midRadius,
    bottom: tabBarHeight - midRadius,
  }}
  onPress={() => {console.log('Do what you want!')}}
/>
```

Comment: its not working I dont get console log statement and when I use touchableOpacity I dont get opacity animation. €: I added zIndex now it works, ty!